# Does the train passing through mean anything?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Periodically (for example, today at 12:49) the level crossing barrier goes down and a train passes through my town without stopping.

Does this have any meaning? Is it a sign of some event triggering / zone changing? Does it always happen along with, or instead of, some other thing in my town?

Or is it just a random occurrence?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is just an atmospheric event.  It doesn't serve any real purpose.

Answer (score 0):

According to people I know on Twitter, the train going by means someone's gate has opened (I am unsure if a second train goes by if a gate closes?). I haven't been able to confirm this conclusively though, and I can't find a second source for this info.

Comment: If so, "someone" isn't anyone on my friend list or nearby.

Comment: I have seen the train passing and I still have no friends in the game.

Comment: My SO and I just tested Ben Brocka's theory. We tried (albeit only once each) opening the gates in both far away and nearby (online and streetpass modes). Neither seemed to cause a train to appear. I'm inclined to believe it is atmospheric as lonewookie says, unless someone else has more information.